# Enable PHP's POSIX functions on Rackspace Cloud Sites

Tags: php, .htaccess, posix, rackspace-cloud

I use Rackspace Cloud Sites for web hosting.  I was trying to use a couple of the `posix_*` functions and noticed that they aren't available.  Using `phpinfo()` I was able to see that `--disable-posix` is part of the "Configure Command".  Also, the `disable_functions` directive has this string `leak,posix_getpwuid,posix_getpwnam,posix_getgrid,posix_getgrnam,posix_getgroups`.

Is there a way to override this using `.htaccess`? I didn't see any mention of it in the manual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Configure commands like --disable-posix are part of the compilation process.

Unless they let you compile and run your own build of PHP (I'm not familiar with RackSpace Cloud), you can't change that.

Comment: I'm accepting this answer because of the explanation of `--disable-posix` being part of the compilation process.

Answer (score 1):

No.  They are disabled for a reason.  That's the price you pay for using Rackspace Cloud Sites.  If you need to enable stuff and change configuration settings beyond what .htaccess allows you to do, you'll need to setup a Rackspace Cloud Server for your web hosting (which is not managed by Rackspace b.t.w.)

Edit: Though I should clarify what I meant by "not managed by Rackspace"... They manage the hardware, but not the software that goes on your server.  That's completely up to you.